# Need help building a Selenium Java Class file from cmd line

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I'm trying to cmd line compile a .java selenium test script into a class file that I can run from the command line.

All of my selenium jar files and all other supporting jar and lib files are in C:\JarFiles

My CLASSPATH is set to C:\WDJarFiles*

I am working at the command line here: C:\EclipseIDEworkspace\MC3\src\Tasks

My .class files are located here C:\EclipseIDEworkspace\MC3\bin\Tasks and I'd like to be able to update them at that location.

My folder structure was set up by using Eclipse IDE so I'd like to keep the existing folder structure but now I want to be able to compile my .java files from the command line and update the .class files.

So, when I run javac like this:

```
javac Edit.java
```

It compiles OK and the .class file gets created in the same folder where I am running the javac command -- but -- I also get a huge number of other .class files in this same directory! These look like supporting class files.

I'm not sure what my cmd line javac syntax should be to:

1. Compile my .java file so its .class file gets updated in the C:\EclipseIDEworkspace\MC3\bin\Tasks folder.
2. I don't get all those other .class files created in my working folder C:\EclipseIDEworkspace\MC3\src\Tasks

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0):

You should try the '-d' option to specify an output directory:

```
javac Edit.java -d ..\..\bin\Tasks
```

About the multiple other .class files, you probably have many nested classes into your `Edit.java` file?

Comment: prompt>javac Edit.java -d C:\EclipseIDEworkspace\MC3\bin\Tasks
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
There was no updating of the .jar file or the .class file

Comment: it most probably means that nothing changed since the last build from Eclipse

Comment: I edited that one Edit.java file and saved it...so it should have seen that it had been changed.

Comment: Not if the instructions are still the same. Did you change the instructions?

Comment: This line didn't produce any changes:
C:\EclipseIDEworkspace\MC3\src\Tasks>javac -cp C:\JarFiles\* EditDetails.java -d C:\EclipseIDEworkspace\MC3\bin\Tasks

Comment: Maybe because I'm also getting these lines after the compile attempt:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.